# GSAP onComplete function doesn't fire when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap, scrollmagic, react-scrollmagic

I'm using `react-gsap` and `react-scrollmagic` and am trying to fire a function when the animation completes. It works well when I scroll down, however, when I scroll up the function doesn't fire. I couldn't find any reference to this problem in `react-gsap` [documentation](https://bitworking.github.io/react-gsap/src-components-tween). Is there any solution to this?

```
    <Controller>
      <Scene triggerHook={0} duration={duration} pin={{ pushFollowers: false }}>
        {(progress) => (
          <Timeline totalProgress={progress} target={<p>wohoo</p>}>
            <Tween
              from={{ opacity: "0" }}
              to={{ opacity: "1" }}
              onStart={() => console.log("Complete!")} // Works only when scrolling down
              onComplete={() => console.log("Complete!")} // Works only when scrolling down
            />
          </Timeline>
        )}
      </Scene>
    </Controller>
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging I found that I can use `onReverseComplete` callback function like so:

```
            <Tween
              from={{ opacity: "0" }}
              to={{ opacity: "1" }}
              onComplete={() => console.log("Complete!")} // Works when scrolling down
              onReverseComplete={()=>console.log("Complete!")} // Works when scrolling up
            />
```